# NSolve with numerical function

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I would like to solve numerically an equation which involves a numerical function constructed by fitting some data:

```
data := {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {.2, 3}, {.4, 5}, {.6, 2}};
try[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ] := (auy = y;
solution = FindFit[data, A (aux - auy) + B Exp[aux - auy], {A, B}, aux];
myFit[aux_?NumberQ] = (A (aux - auy) + B Exp[aux - auy]) /. 
solution; Return[myFit[x]])

NSolve[y - try[1, y] == 0, y]
```

I tried with this code but it does not function (various errors). Does anyone know how to help me?

thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you even try to test call your try function? What happens when you type `try[1, y]` ? does not return anything? This is really strange that no body seems to do any testing of anything any more.

Comment: I tried `try[1,2]` and it works. `try[1,y]` has not to return an output since it need numerical parameters to work. What I want is a way to solve the problem I described, i.e. using NSolve to solve the equation which involve a function numerically determined by a fit. My code obviously does not work, that's why I asked help. Does anyone knows how to solve my issue? I hope I clarified my post!

Comment: I modified a little the example code above, now it should be more clear.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {.2, 3}, {.4, 5}, {.6, 2}};
try[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, data_] := (A (x - y) + B Exp[x - y]) /.  
                                        FindFit[data, A (xx - y) + B Exp[xx - y], {A, B}, xx]

FindRoot[y - try[1, y, data] == 0, {y, 1}]

(*
 {y -> 1.78209}
*)
```

Comment: ok, this helps a lot: FindRoot is what I need. But I have to scal a big range of "y", right? Maybe with a `Do[ ]` statement. is there someway to optimize it?. Thank you for your help belisarius!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your sentence `But I have to scal a big range of "y", right?`. Can you explain it further for me, please?

Comment: I am really sorry, I had to write "scan" and not "scal".
What I meant is that I have to search for solution in a range of `y`s to find more than one solution.

Comment: @user9994 FindRoot should take care of that. Just try to give it a good initial guess

Comment: But if I suspect the existence of different solutions I  have to repeat the FindRoot with different intial guesses right?

Comment: @user9994 Try to show an example of such case, please

Comment: trivially, if I have `FindRoot[x^2 - 4 == 0, {x, x0}]` to see both solutions I have to repeat the FindRoot twice, one with x0 near -2 (for example -0.1) and the other with x0 near 2 (for ex. +0.1). Therefore in my case I have to perform a Do statement to searh solutions near different values of x0.

Comment: @user9994 I am aware that an equation can have more than one root. What I asked you for was an example of a `data` set showing that property for the current problem :)